# List fe_users TYPO3

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3

So I want to list all the users from the table `fe_users` on the frontend, but I have a problem creating the extension. Here is my Extension

[image]

I'm doing something wrong? This is what happens when I press save

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, I can see no reason why you are using two classes. You should only use one class, which extends the frontend user and add your custom fields there. Extbase already has a base class for frontend users and groups which you can extend. You will find [some examples](http://www.derhansen.de/2012/12/typo3-extbase-mapping-existing-fields.html) when you google it.

Comment: So you are saying that I should do something like this: map to existing table: fe_users and Tx_Extbase_Domain_Model_FrontendUser

Comment: Yes. The class may then be extended by adding more fields, relations and so on (like `skype` in your example).

Comment: Still doesn't work: http://screencast.com/t/12UBBfBzRsFi `Fatal error: Class '....\ArxUsers\Domain\Model\Tx_Extbase_Domain_Model_FrontendUser' not found in C:\...`

Comment: The model class should not be loaded from there. Do you `require` or `include` the class somewhere?